# Спросил-таки-то (дефисы)

Tags: пунктуация

Розенталь таки говорит, что если есть вместе-таки две частицы, то мы никаких дефисов не ставим-таки (кроме случая с *-с*). Однако Розенталь-то нам даёт только примеры, где первая частица пишется уже без дефиса, и говорит, что в данном таки случае мы ко второй частице, даже если её надо писать было бы в обычном таки случае через-то дефис, мы не прибавляем дефис.

В связи с этим-то делом возникли-таки у меня вопросы, совы мудрые, для Вас таки, а именно:

1. Если мы к частице, которую надо через дефис писать-таки, прибавляем ещё частицу, которую надо через дефис писать, то мы это как в конце концов таки пишем-то?

Например (как правильно писать-то?): *1) Я **что-нибудь-то** для тебя сделаю, а ты мне плюнешь в спину, как предатель!; 2) Я **спросил-таки-с**, как у него раскопка-то **прошла-таки-то**; 3) **Кстати-ка-с**, сова, как у тебя дела на работе-с?*

2. Розенталь также говорит, что когда мы говорим насчёт частицы, которая через дефис пишется, и о том, чтобы ей, так сказать, разделить слово, которое имеет две части, через дефис таки написанные, то мы дефис только перед этой частицей ставим-таки. (Он конкретно про *-то* говорит, но я полагаю, что это ко всем-то частицам, которые через дефис пишутся, относится.) Поэтому мой вопрос такой: а если частица не через дефис пишется и мы ею слово разделяем, то как правило писать? Вообще без дефисов?

Примеры (как правильно?): *1) **Коты же искатели** мои нашли сокровище.* (Без частицы было бы "коты-искатели".)

Comment: Спросил-таки-то,  что-нибудь-то и тп слов не существует, но если вы выступаете-таки автором, то можете писать хоть через три дефиса  что-нибудь-то-с или больше. Коты же искатели мои ... - не выглядит согласованным предложением. Коты же мои искатели - нашли сокровище.

Comment: Нельзя использовать и "-то", и "-таки": "-таки" буквально означает "всё-таки" (*спросил всё-таки-то*), это как слово при слове, и получается что-то типа примыкания ко фразе. После "что-нибудь" нельзя "-то", оно подчёркивает слова с конкретным смыслом, а у "что-нибудь" его нет. У вас какие-то частицы-паразиты.